# MATLAB MPI Initialization error

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, mpi

I'm running a Genetic Algorithm in parallel. I'm using the default option in MATLAB ('UseParallel','always'). However, I would like to integrate results and write to a file as each design gets evaluated. Since I dont want the same file to be accessed by all processors, I want to send all the data to a single worker/processor and make just that processor write to file.

However when I use the labSend and labReceive commands, I get an error saying "the MPI implementation has not yet been loaded. Please call mpiInit". Also, despite running in parallel when I display my labindex, it is always 1 (although it says 8 labs opened!!)

I'm doing all this inside the 'fitness function' which I assume is made parallel among all labs! Can someone tell me if I'm missing something? Have I not understood the implicit parallel process correctly? Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you called mpiInit?

Comment: I did try with this syntax:
MPI_Init;

However I'm still not able to transfer data among labs because my labindex is always 1 despite poolsize being 8.